# Error retrieving using date query in mongodb from Grails gmongo

Tags: java, json, mongodb, groovy

I have a string as:

```
'"startDate" : {"\\$gte" : new Date() }'
```

I actually want to query my mongodb database collection for all the collections with dates after the present date.Here is a sample document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51e2a857adc0c2fb535f6904"),
  "dateInfo" : {
    "dates" : {
      "startDate" : ISODate("2013-07-13T04:00:00Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2013-07-19T20:00:00Z")
    },
    "named" : "name1",
    "fieldX" : "field1",
    "contact" : {
      "numbs" : ["+44 121 127 127", "+44 568 789 256", "+44 687 5788 9875"]
    }
  },
  "Locality" : "locality1",
  "type" : "ewhet"
}
```

from mongo shell, I am able to query it as follows:

```
db.collectionName.find({"dateInfo.dates.startDate" : {"$gte" : new Date()}})
```

Now I want to do it from groovy. I am trying to do it as(using [mongoDB java api](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29)):

```
DBCursor cursor = db.collectionName.find(new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"startDate" : {"\$gte" : new Date() }}'))
```

Above code gives error as:

```
Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 48, while reading 'new ', was trying to match the constant 'null'
```

Now the problem with JsonSlurper is that it requires double quotes in both key and value names.But in case I put a double quote in `new Date()`, it wont be evaluated by mongodb.

So what can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
db.collectionName.find( [ 'dateInfo.dates.startDate' : ['$gte' : new Date() ] ] )
```

Comment: Kindly read my question carefully.I want to get it done in groovy, not in mongodb shell.And with the libraries I have tried, all need the keys and values to be in double quotes.So ['$gte' : new Date()] would result in exception since new Date() is not in quotes.

Comment: Yes thats valid in groovy also, but wont get parsed by JSONSlurper as new Date() is without quotes.Try that yourself to see if it works for u.Does not works for my case!!

Comment: But why are you passing it through jsonslurper? DbObject is a map, so groovy can just pass maps into it

Comment: No actually to change from json to MAP would require major design changes for my case.So I am looking for some hack!!

Comment: What you currently have is invalid json, so I guess something is going to have to change? Maybe get the bit which writes `new Date()` to write an iso format date or something that can be templated?